# Building a decision-making game in jQuery? Where would I store data

Tags: jquery

I built a slideshow/decision-making game in Flash but would like to try to redo it using jQuery.

The slideshow part seems simple enough, however I have a series of user decisions that I'm not sure how to approach.

In flash, if the user makes a decision, I would just store this in a variable or shared local objects, is this the same for jQuery? i.e. mix regular javascript variables with the jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store it in a object, as easy as:

```
var myDecisions = {};
```

Or an array: `var myDecisions = [];`

Or on the element itself if it's related to an element with jQuery like this:

```
$('#thing5').data("decision", "good decision"); //Set
var decision = $('#thing5').data("decision"); //Get
```

Answer (score 0):

store it in a closure, or a global variable.

regular javascript variables are no different then jquery variables. its all javascript.